# Loop/ or apply function to feed list of igraph objects into function in R

Tags: r, igraph

I want to create a list of igraph objects, and then feed this list into two functions that model information diffusion. Specifically, I would like to generate a list of randomly generated small-world and scale free networks, then feed these lists into two functions that apply the independent cascade and linear threshold models of information diffusion.

I can create a list of 1000 unique scale-free igraph objects (size 100 nodes) using lapply:

```
sample <- as.list(rep(100, 1000))
                 
list <- lapply(X = sample, FUN = sample_pa)
```

However, this does not work as easily for the small-world function that requires parameters:

```
sample <- as.list(rep(100, 1000))

list <- lapply(X = sample, FUN = sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 100, nei = 2, p = 0.25))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
'sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 100, nei = 2, p = 0.25)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

I would then like to feed this list of igraph objects into several functions from the  [influence.maximization package](https://github.com/seekme94/influence.mining):

```
# independent cascade:
out <- influence_ic(g, seeds, 1000, 0.5))
# linear threshold:
out2 <- influence_lt(g, seeds, 1000, 0.5)
```

These functions accept an igraph object (g, which would be my list created above), seeds (list of initial active nodes), steps (number of times to run) and a probability or threshold of activation (0.5 in my example)

How can I fix my lapply code to accept the sample_smallworld() function, and how might I go about feeding these lists of igraph objects into these influence functions? Ultimately I want to have a dataframe or list of the number of activated nodes from each of the 1000 unique igraph objects.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply()` works by passing elements of `X` into the first position of the function listed under the `FUN` argument. Then any additional parameters can be passed in by name with the `...`.

It seems like you wish elements of `sample` to be passed in as values to the `size` argument of `sample_smallworld()`. Therefore, it might be easiest to define your own function to rearrange the order of the arguments to more easily work with `lapply()` like so:

```r
hundos <- as.list(rep(100, 1000))

my_sample_smallworld <- function(size, ...) {
  igraph::sample_smallworld(size = size, ...)
}

gs <- lapply(X = hundos, 
             FUN = my_sample_smallworld,
             dim = 1, 
             nei = 2, 
             p = 0.25)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The application of `lapply()` with this other package's functions would be the same as with `sample_pa()` because the objects you wish to pass in are to be passed as the first argument. Therefore you do not need to write a custom function:

```r
out <- lapply(X = gs, 
              FUN = influence_ic, 
              seed = 1, 
              steps = 1000, 
              prob = 0.5)

out2 <- lapply(X = gs, 
               FUN = influence_lt, 
               seed = 1, 
               steps = 1000, 
               prob = 0.5)
```

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you. What if i wanted to have different seeds every time in the lapply function? For example I can generate a random list of nodes to be seeds using this code:seeds <- sample.int(100, 5), but how can i make it so that it is a different set of nodes everytime in the lapply function?

Comment: I am not that familiar with these specific functions, but in general, to use a different value for an optional argument on each pass of `lapply()` you will likely need to define your own function which generates seeds within its body each time it is called. This can be achieved with an inline anonymous function, something like: `lapply(X = gs, FUN = function(graph) influence_ic(graph = graph, seed = sample.int(100, 5), steps = 1000, prob = 0.5))`